# SplideJS slider - if LAST or FIRST slide item of Array returns null error

Tags: javascript, slider

I am using the Splide JS slider. I have created two buttons to display the Previous/Next Sibling Element innerText based on the Current Active index.

I am replacing years for instance, 2019, 2020, 2021, etc if the current is 2020 previous button is 2019, and next is 2021.

I am able to go to Next and Previous. However, when I Am reaching the last slide  I get 'TextContent/Innertext" error of NULL. Same story when I reverse it.

My Code:

```
import Splide from '@splidejs/splide';

(() => {
    const timeline = document.querySelector('.timeline-container');

    if (!timeline) {
        return;
    }

    const map = document.querySelector('[data-gebiedsontwikkeling="map"]');
    const navigation = document.querySelector(
        '[data-gebiedsontwikkeling="navigatie"]'
    );

    // Navigatie buttons
    let btnPrevYear = document.querySelector('.btn--slide-prev');
    let btnNextYear = document.querySelector('.btn--slide-next');

    // Map opties
    const mapOptions = {
        // Start bij 2de (0 index).
        lazyLoad: 'nearby',
        pagination: false,
        arrows: false,
        start: 1,
        perPage: 1,
        type: 'fade'
    };

    // Navigatie opties
    const navigationOptions = {
        isNavigation: false,
        pagination: false,
        drag: false,
        easing: 'cubic-bezier(.785, .135, .15, .86)',
        focus: 'center',
        fixedWidth: '8rem',
        width: '27rem',
        gap: '1rem',
        // perPage: 1,
        start: 1
    };

    // Gebiedsontwikkeling - map
    const YearMapSlider = new Splide(map, mapOptions);

    // Gebiedsontwikkeling - navigatie
    const YearNavSlider = new Splide(navigation, navigationOptions).mount();

    // Sync Map & Jaar slider.
    YearMapSlider.sync(YearNavSlider).mount();

    // Events & Functions
    const onActiveSlide = (value) => {
        let currentIndex = value.index;
        let previousYear = value.slide.previousElementSibling.textContent;
        let nextYear = value.slide.nextElementSibling.textContent;

        // Show Next & Previous Year inside button.
        btnPrevYear.innerText = previousYear;
        btnNextYear.innerText = nextYear;

        console.log(currentIndex);
        console.log(value);
    };

    YearNavSlider.on('active', onActiveSlide.bind(this));
    // YearNavSlider.on('arrows:updated', onMounted.bind(this));
})();
```

I am always facing this issue inside Arrays.

API URL: https://splidejs.com/

Trying to add a CHECK if last item inside Array do something else and reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding a CHECK if previousElementSibling and nextElementSibling exist then update text value.